# Symfony Twig - multiple dynamic extend of template

Tags: symfony, templates, dynamic, twig, extends

I have app based on Symfony4, with dynamic plugins stored in db.
Each plugin have own template which could extend base template of app and replace/add some blocks.

I can have active more than 1 plugin.

What i am trying to do:

loop through plugins and dynamically extend base template or template of previous plugin.

For example, result should be dynamically generated:

```
Dashboard.html.twig extends Base.html.twig
Plugin1_dashboard.html.twig extends Dashboard.html.twig
Plugin2_dashobard.html.twig extends Plugin1_dashboard.html.twig
```

Any suggestions how to do this?

Is there a way to some partial render to keep value of previous extend in variable?

I don't want to hardcode plugin includes to base template.

Comment: implementing dynamic templates means you will also have to refresh the template caches, so be aware of that. I also only had bad experiences with extension chains and would generally advise against them unless you know what you're doing ...

Comment: situation as explained above is still possible but indeed after modification in the plugins by the user you will have to clear the cache which is possible on runtime in production mode. Also two plugins that extends dashboard.html are not possible be aware of that. It should be better to embed controllers like {{ render(controller(
        'App\\Controller\\BlogController::recentArticles', {max: 3}
    )) }} see https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers